# How to pass a custom analyzer to @Indexed annotation?

Tags: full-text-indexing, spring-data-neo4j

Neo4J lets us provide a custom *[Analyzer](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-create-advanced.html)* when creating indexes.

How can we achieve this with Spring-Data-Neo4j? Since **@Indexed** doesn't have this property, what are other options?